# A reference about a problem of the number of the rational points on a projective scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, finite-fields

Let $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{F}_q}$ be a pure dimensional projective scheme of dimension $d$. So we know a trivial estimate of the number of $X(\mathbb F_q)$ is that $\#X(\mathbb F_q)\leqslant\deg(X)(q^d+\cdots+1)$.

I want to know where I can find a reference of the proof of this result. Only requirement is that it must be a "published" reference.

Thank you.

Comment: The argument that leads to that upper bound is, essentially, contained in p. 236 of Barry Mazur's Arcata contribution, "Eigenvalues of Frobenius acting on algebraic varieties over finite fields."

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thank you very much, Prof. Starr.